# Infinite Huffman Tree

Tags: information-theory, huffman-coding

We have to derive an optimal binary encoding for the infinite set of symbols $\{s_1, s_2, \dots \}$. Their distribution is given by
$$p(s_i) = 9 \cdot 10^{-i}$$

My intuition was to use a Huffman encoding. Obviously the Huffman encoding
algorithm needs to first find the smallest two elements, which we can't do. But, if we imagine the last step of the Huffman algorithm, it would have the two elements $s_1$ and the supersymbol $s_2s_3s_4\dots$ with probabilities $0.9$ and $0.1$ respectively. Thus, (if left is $0$ and right is $1$) symbol $s_1$ would get codeword $0$. The other symbols would all get a codeword starting with $1$. This tree is clearly self similar. If we represent binary trees as tuples with an empty tree as the nullset $\varnothing$, we have that this tree is given by

$$ T = (\varnothing, T) $$

That is, a left branch which is empty an the right branch which is identical to the whole tree. Thus, we get the codewords

$$ s_1 \mapsto 0, s_2 \mapsto 10, s_3 \mapsto 110, s_4 \mapsto 1110, \dots $$

Now, I know that these are optimal. You can do a proof by contradiction showing that changing any of these codewords and still satisfying the Kraft inequality will cause the expected length to increase.

My question is, is the fact that this infinite Huffman tree arrived at the answer a coincidence or is there a way to formalize Huffman encoding for an infinite set of symbols.

Comment: The natural thing to try is to take the $n$ most frequent element and put all of the rest of the mass into a new element; compute a Huffman tree; and hope that the process converges.

Comment: Oh shoot ok. This definitely converges using that procedure. Does that always lead to an optimal codeword assignments? (minimizing expecting codeword length)

Comment: You can try proving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is an algorithm that works for any infinite probability distribution. However, you have taken the case of a geometric distribution for which there happens to be a neat answer. It was proposed by Gallager in this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1055357) [1]. So if you apply his algorithm, you will see that you obtain exactly the same answer you proposed.

---

[1] Gallager, R., & Van Voorhis, D. (1975). Optimal source codes for geometrically distributed integer alphabets (corresp.). *IEEE Transactions on Information theory, 21*(2), 228-230.

Answer (score 1):

You already have an infinite sequence for the infinite Huffman encoding.

What is the average codeword length? Does that tell you anything more?